# how to determine the resonance frequency of a split ring resonator?

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

how to determine the resonance frequency of this Split Ring Resonator ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking for an answer on google?

Comment: For example http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/32229696.PDF

Answer (score -1):

Look for "mertamaterials srr and csrr" on youtube where you got the above picture. The  video gave the resonant frequencies by formula.

Comment: This answer does not stand on its own, since it will become useless if the video in question is removed, made private, or changes its title significantly. Please edit your post to include the formulae with appropriate attribution, as well as possibly some notes on their derivation.

Answer (score -1):

See this paper: "Design and Application of a Metamaterial Superstrate on a Bio-Inspired Antenna for Partial Discharge Detection through Dielectric Windows", the equations are given.